# raytracing in python: intersection of a polygon and a ray

Tags: python, scipy, raytracing

This seems like a common graphics problem, but I don't seem to find anything that does what I want in python:

I have many 4-vertex polygons in 3D space and need to calculate for a given ray which of the polygons is intercepted first and where. So it is basically ray-tracing of those surfaces to see which is in front. I want to do that for a x-y grid of rays to calculate an image. Below is some simple sample data and I would want to basically see two squares where one overlaps the other. I can do that with a 3D plot, but I need the actual values for a given ray, so for example for a y-directed ray from x=0.75, z=0.75, I need to find the y value where the foremost polygon is hit.

Hope this problem is clear. Ideally only common libraries like `scipy`, `numpy`, ... are used, but any help is appreciated!

The 5th point in the example-polygons below is just to plot a closed shape.

```
square1 = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0.5, 1],
    [0, 0.5, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]])

square2 = square1 + 0.5 * np.ones_like(square1)

# 3D plot of this projection

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d', proj_type='ortho')
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 2)
#ax.axis('off')
ax.plot(*square1[:,:].T)
ax.plot(*square2[:,:].T)
ax.view_init(elev=0., azim=-90)

# 2D plot of the projection

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot(*square1[:,[0,2]].T)
ax.plot(*square2[:,[0,2]].T)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: given N 4-point polygons in 3D, what is the y value where the foremost polygon is hit (given a ray in y direction).

Comment: What if the ray doesn't hit the polygon at all?

Comment: sure, then that's also a valid answer. could be -infinty or an empty list of intersections.